# Left and Right String Alignment in Haskell

Tags: python-3.x, string, haskell

I am used to working with Python and fairly new to Haskell.

I was wondering how strings are left/right aligned in Haskell and  if there exist  equivalent functions to the following Python functions in Haskell:

```
str = "Hello stackoverflow."

# Printing a left aligned string  
print (str.ljust(40)) 

# Printing a right aligned string  
print (str.rjust(40))
```

Comment: Pay attention to difference between `String` and `Text`! `putStrLn` takes `String` but decent alignment module exist only which takes `Text`.

Comment: Usually when such a thing is needed, the more abstract [`prettyprinter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter) or [`boxes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/boxes) libraries are a better choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically for text processing, `Text` is used and not `String`s, since `Text` works with an array of *unboxed* unicode characters. One can justify with [**`justifyLeft :: Int -> Char -> Text -> Text`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.4.0/docs/Data-Text.html#v:justifyLeft) and [**`justifyRight :: Int -> Char -> Text -> Text`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.4.0/docs/Data-Text.html#v:justifyRight). For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text(Text, justifyLeft, justifyRight)
import Data.Text.IO as TI

myText :: Text
myText = "Hello stackoverflow."

main :: IO ()
main = do
    TI.putStrLn (justifyLeft 40 ' ' myText)
    TI.putStrLn (justifyRight 40 ' ' myText)
```

The `' '` is here the character used as "fill character". For example if we use `justifyLeft 40 '#' myText` and `justifyRight 40 '#' myText` instead, we get:

```
Hello stackoverflow.####################
####################Hello stackoverflow.
```

Answer (score 2):

@WillemVanOnsem has already given a good answer for how to justify `Text`s. But, for completeness, the equivalent functions for `String` (or indeed any list) are:

```
justifyLeft, justifyRight :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
justifyLeft  n c s = s ++ replicate (n - length s) c
justifyRight n c s = replicate (n - length s) c ++ s
```

(I don’t believe these are predefined anywhere, but they’re easy enough to define yourself.)